# convert t-sql replace code to C#

Tags: c#, t-sql

```
RETURN (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@input, @class_text, '~~|~'), @id_text, @class_text), '~~|~', @id_text))
```

where @input is string.

How to convert this in C# with the same parameters...

```
@class_text is class_text in C#, etc..
```

Comment: You might be better served by identifying the problem you are trying to solve rather than the approaches you are attempting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059893/mssql-tsql-procedure-replace-order and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065469/how-to-change-string-element-position-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input = input.Replace(class_text, "~~|~").Replace(id_text, class_text).Replace("~~|~", id_text);
```

simple as that

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL's `REPLACE` actually has different arguments. E.g.,

```
REPLACE(string1, string2, replaceText)
```

Where it is searching for `string1` within `string2`, whereas, it is generally:

```
string1.Replace(string2, replaceText)
```

...in .NET, where you are searching for `string2` in `string1`. For large amounts of string replaces, I'd recommend the `StringBuilder`.

```
var builder = new Stringbuilder(input);
builder = builder.Replace(class_text, "~~|~").Replace(id_text, class_text).Replace("~~|~", id_text)

string result = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

1) make a string

```
String myOldString = "No way";
```

2) Use the replace function

```
String myNewString = myOldString.Replace("No", "Yes");
```

Here's the MSDN for more detailed information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx#Y480

**EDIT**
Here's the data from your post:

```
String myInput = "whatever @input equals"
String myclass_text = "whatever @class_text equals"
String myid_text = "whatever @id_text equals"

String myString = myInput.replace(myclass_text, "~~|~")
myString = myString.replace(myid_text, class_text)
myString = myString.replace("~~|~", myid_text)
```

Or all-in-one (I don't know if c# lets you piggy-back like this, but if prefer one-liners, give it a try:

```
String myString = myInput.replace(myclass_text, "~~|~").replace(myid_text, myclass_text).replace("~~|~", myid_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Converted the TSQL to C#, which could have been requested in original question [How to change string element position in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065469/how-to-change-string-element-position-in-c)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Given a line of text, swap position of class and id tags.
    /// Id should always precede class tag
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input"><td class="m92_t_col5" id="preis_0">xx</td></param>
    /// <returns><td id="preis_0" class="m92_t_col5">xx</td></returns>
    public static string SwapClassAndId(string input)
    {
        string output = string.Empty;
        int classOrdinal = 0;
        int classOridnalEndQuotes = 0;
        string classText = string.Empty;

        int idOrdinal = 0;
        int idOrdinalEndQuotes = 0;
        string idText = string.Empty;

        classOrdinal = input.IndexOf("class=");
        classOridnalEndQuotes = input.IndexOf("\"", classOrdinal + 7) + 1;

        idOrdinal = input.IndexOf("id=");
        idOrdinalEndQuotes = input.IndexOf("\"", idOrdinal + 4) + 1;

        if (idOrdinal < classOrdinal)
        {
            return input;
        }

        classText = input.Substring(classOrdinal, classOridnalEndQuotes - classOrdinal);
        idText = input.Substring(idOrdinal, idOrdinalEndQuotes - idOrdinal);

        output = input.Replace(classText, "~~|~").Replace(idText, classText).Replace("~~|~", idText);

        return output;
    }
```